# piping input to command fails if not consumed

Tags: c, pipe

For a command interpreter that allows users to run any shell command with input redirection, I'm trying to pipe input to a command with the following C code.

This works for commands which actually consume the piped input (e. g. cat), but piping fails for commands which ignore stdin (e. g. echo).

The failure is silent, no error indication, no segmentation fault, no message.

I'm testing this on Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc 5 and gcc 6.
I assume that the command finishes, somehow taking with it the pipe, but why is there no error indication?
Help appreciated.

```
#include <spawn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int in[2];
  int pid;
  posix_spawn_file_actions_t action;
  char* spawnedArgs[] = { NULL, NULL };
  int status;

  const char* line = "123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 ";
  int line_length = strlen(line);

  if (argc < 3) { printf("syntax: spawn reps command\n"); return 1; }
  int reps = atoi(argv[1]);
  spawnedArgs[0] = argv[2];

  pipe(in);

  posix_spawn_file_actions_init(&action);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2(&action, in[0], 0);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose(&action, in[1]);
  posix_spawnp(&pid, spawnedArgs[0], &action, NULL, spawnedArgs, NULL);

  close(in[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i <= reps; i++)
  {
    printf("#%i: %zd\n", i, write(in[1], line, line_length));
  }
  close(in[1]);
  printf("input piped\n");

  wait(&status);
  posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy(&action);

  return 0;
}
```

This is a sample output of a failing command

```
$ ./spawn 100 "echo 123"
#1: 100
#2: 100
#3: 100
#4: 100
#5: 100
#6: 100
#7: 100
#8: 100
#9: 100
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Your program gets hung writing to the pipe; when the child exits without reading anything, your program gets a SIGPIPE, and the default reaction to SIGPIPE is to exit immediately without a core dump.  You should ignore SIGPIPE and spot the error from the `write()` — EPIPE (broken pipe).  Also note that if you don't write more data to the pipe than fits in the buffer, you may never spot that the data is not consumed.  You might write all the data to the pipe buffer while there are still child processes available to read it.

Comment: You also need to be aware that if the child processes read the data, there's no guarantee that they'd each get some of the data, even though you wrote one message for each child.  It depends on how the children do the reading.  Pipe buffers on Linux are 64 KiB, I believe.  Ten lots of 100 bytes isn't going to fill anything.

Comment: You should also elaborate on what you mean by "piping fails for commands which ignore stdin".  The creation of the pipe doesn't fail.  The data can be written to the pipe.  That the child process ignores its input is neither here nor there; it simply means the effort of creating the pipe an writing to it was wasted.  Just because you run `echo "Hi" < /etc/passwd` doesn't mean there's a problem when the whole input file is ignored by `echo`.  So, you need to explain what you expect to see, and why you expect to see it — to yourself even if not to SO.  And consider whether you want to keep this.

Comment: @Retr0id: the expected behavior was write() to return the number of bytes written, or -1 for an error.  I was not aware of SIGPIPE.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: thanks, I'll look into ignoring SIGPIPE.  The failure I was seeing, was write() ending the program instead of returning number of bytes written or a -1 error indication. There was no complaint about echo ignoring stdin.